# Not understand struct Barnyard2's sf_ip header file

Tags: c, struct

I am looking at Barnyard2's sf_ip.h [source code](https://github.com/firnsy/barnyard2/blob/master/src/sfutil/sf_ip.h). I am not understanding the sfip_t stuct, particulary the union block.

```
typedef struct _ip {
    int family;
    int bits;

    /* see sfip_size(): these address bytes
* must be the last field in this struct */
    union
    {
        u_int8_t u6_addr8[16];
        u_int16_t u6_addr16[8];
        u_int32_t u6_addr32[4];
// u_int64_t u6_addr64[2];
    } ip;
    #define ip8 ip.u6_addr8
    #define ip16 ip.u6_addr16
    #define ip32 ip.u6_addr32
// #define ip64 ip.u6_addr64
} sfip_t;
```

Why is it using arrays? I tried to look for documentation but Google has been of no luck. Can anyone explain what is being done here please?

Comment: the union means that you can use three ways to specify ip address with byte, word and double word array. they reserve 16 bytes to hold the ip address. why do you worry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A union in C uses the *same* memory block for all its elements. This is distinct from a structure, in which the elements are consecutive in memory.

So, while `struct {int x; int y;}` would be laid out thus if your variable started at memory location `0x40000000`:

```
           +-------------+
0x40000000 | x (4 bytes) |
           +-------------+
0x40000004 | y (4 bytes) |
           +-------------+
```

a related `union {int x; int y;}` exists like this:

```
Address
           +-------------+-------------+
0x40000000 | x (4 bytes) | y (4 bytes) |
           +-------------+-------------+
```

In other words, it can only be used for *one* thing at a time and, technically, it's undefined behaviour to use `y` when you last used `x` to set the variable - though in this case, you'll most likely find it will work since the two possibilities are the same type.

In your particular case, you have the following memory layout (assuming your variable was located at `0x40000000`):

```
           +--------------+--------------+--------------+
0x40000000 | u6_addr8[ 0] |              |              |
           +--------------+ u6_addr16[0] |              |
0x40000001 | u6_addr8[ 1] |              |              |
           +--------------+--------------+ u6_addr32[0] |
0x40000002 | u6_addr8[ 2] |              |              |
           +--------------+ u6_addr16[1] |              |
0x40000003 | u6_addr8[ 3] |              |              |
           +--------------+--------------+--------------+
0x40000004 | u6_addr8[ 4] |              |              |
           +--------------+ u6_addr16[2] |              |
0x40000005 | u6_addr8[ 5] |              |              |
           +--------------+--------------+ u6_addr32[1] |
0x40000006 | u6_addr8[ 6] |              |              |
           +--------------+ u6_addr16[3] |              |
0x40000007 | u6_addr8[ 7] |              |              |
           +--------------+--------------+--------------+
0x40000008 | u6_addr8[ 8] |              |              |
           +--------------+ u6_addr16[4] |              |
0x40000009 | u6_addr8[ 9] |              |              |
           +--------------+--------------+ u6_addr32[2] |
0x4000000a | u6_addr8[10] |              |              |
           +--------------+ u6_addr16[5] |              |
0x4000000b | u6_addr8[11] |              |              |
           +--------------+--------------+--------------+
0x4000000c | u6_addr8[12] |              |              |
           +--------------+ u6_addr16[6] |              |
0x4000000d | u6_addr8[13] |              |              |
           +--------------+--------------+ u6_addr32[3] |
0x4000000e | u6_addr8[14] |              |              |
           +--------------+ u6_addr16[7] |              |
0x4000000f | u6_addr8[15] |              |              |
           +--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Assuming you understand how your particular C implementation lays out various types, this provides a way to reference the same data in different ways.